# Update object property state inside of watch vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to update the selected boolean to true from my lists items array of objects when the from_id property from the items array inside of the entry object matches with the item_id of the object in lists fromData array. The selected property updates but I got this error:

```
Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

**store.js**

```
entry: {
    items: [
        {
            from_id: 5,
            to_id: 1,
            quantity: 100,
        },
        {
            from_id: 11,
            to_id: 3,
            quantity: 119,
        },
        {
            from_id: 7,
            to_id: 3,
            quantity: 59,
        },
    ]
}

lists: {
    from: [
        {
            item: {...},
            item_id: 5,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            item: {...},
            item_id: 6,
            selected: false,
        },
        {
            item: {...},
            item_id: 7,
            selected: false,
        }
    ]
}

const getters = {
  entry: (state) => state.entry,
  lists: (state) => state.lists,
};
```

**This what I've tried**

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('Conversion', ['entry', 'lists']),

    from: function () {
      return this.lists.from.filter((item) => !item.selected);
    },
},

watch: {
    from: {
        deep: true,
        handler: function (items) {
        const _entries = this.entry.items;

        _entries.map((entry) => {
          items
            .filter((item) => item.item_id === entry.item_from_id)
            .map((item) => (item.selected = !item.selected));
        });
      },
    },
},
```

Comment: The error means what it says. You're mutating the state outside the store. Don't do this. This should happen in mutation/action

Comment: How can I mutate the object inside the watch? Is it possible?

Comment: Dispatch an action.

Comment: I'd like to update the selected property to true when the from_id of items array is equal to the item_id from the 'from' array inside the lists object. Are there any solution for this?

Comment: You need to have an action/mutation that modifies the state this way. And dispatch/commit it. It's as simple as it sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means what it says. You're mutating the state outside the store. This should happen in mutation/action.

You need to have an action/mutation that modifies the state this way:

```
mutations: {
  toggle(state, id) {
    let item = state.items.find(item => item.id === id)
    item.selected = !item.selected;
  }
}
```

And dispatch/commit it outside the store:

```
this.$store.dispatch('toggle', someId)
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass multiple ids from the toggle action? Can you show me how? I'd like to update multiple selected property from the object when the page load.

Comment: You can pass `ids` param instead of `id` and modify `state.items` in `forEach` or `for` loop

Comment: It works now. But I got this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selected') even if selected property is existing.

Comment: It's not about missing selected key, it's about accessing it on non-object. Depends on your current code. In the code above it means that no item was found

Comment: Is there any fix for that problem?

Comment: What I did is I've created a computed property that returns the entry items and in watcher I map the entry items and pass the entry items from_id to the the mutation/action.

Comment: The fix is to use if statement in any place where `item` may not exist. Not sure if it's applicable to your case. Can you post current code, so it could be fixed?

Comment: If I update Vuex state using the Vuex watchers, does it affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Vuex is `one-way data flow` store. You will not able to mutate data directly with the getters, use action/mutation instead. https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern

In your store.js

```
const store = createStore({
  ...
  mutations: {
    patchEntry (state, payload) {
      // Your logic here => return _entries
      state.entry = Object.assign({}, state.entry, _entries)
    }
  }
})
```

In your watcher:

```
watch: {
    from: {
        deep: true,
        handler: function (items) {
            store.commit('patchEntry', items)
        });
      },
    },
},
```

Ref: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components